# Material doesn't have a color property '_TintColor'

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I want to modify the `TintColor` of a material using script but while doing it, error below is coming:

> Material doesn't have a color property '_TintColor'

I Googled about it but all efforts in vain.

I read [this post](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/control-the-tint-color-of-the-material.23031/) and it says that it can be modified using script.

The shader that I am using is `Sprites/Default`

```
public Color[] colors = { new Color(42/255.0f, 246/255.0f, 229/255.0f,1),new Color(20/255.0f, 127/255.0f, 255/255.0f,1),new Color(73/255.0f, 3/255.0f, 198/255.0f,1);
Debug.Log(renderer.material.GetColor("_TintColor"));
//renderer.material.SetColor("_TintColor", colors[2]); /*This eventually I want to use */
```

I tried playing with alpha value, but it didn't work

I don't know what I am doing wrong. It would be very helpful if someone can point me out my mistake or let me how to change `TintColor` of a material.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shader `Sprites/Default` does not have a `"_TintColor" property`, but instead a `"_Color"` property. So all you have to do is change

```
Debug.Log(renderer.material.GetColor("_TintColor"));
```

to

```
Debug.Log(renderer.material.GetColor("_Color"));
```

Comment: I have accepted your answer but one question related to this. How do I know if '_TintColor' or '_Color' or any another property is exposed

Comment: @AshishSingh You can view the underlying shader code for the default Unity shaders by [downloading the "Built in shaders"](https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive) for your corresponding Unity version. That should provide you with all the information you need about the various properties on them.

Comment: @AshishSingh. You can click in the context menu of the material (the gear on the top right) and then "Select Shader". You will see all the shader properties